# How to check CPU/HDD temperature under XenServer 5.6?

Tags: xenserver, physical-environment, linux

Is it possible to check the temperature of the CPU and locally attached SATA/IDE HDDs under XenServer 5.6?  Can I install lm-sensors?

Comment: +1 As I run XenServer on high-end desktop, not a "real" server, IPMI/BMC or ILO are completely out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

We use [IPMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) with a BMC controller to do hardware monitoring for our xenserver hosts. Depending on the type of hardware you have this might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) for that.  If those hard drives are in a RAID array, you may be able to pick up the SMART data through the controller.  Be sure to check the "-d" option in the [smartctl man page](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartctl.8.html).

Answer (score 1):

smartmontools will do the job. It is however not trivial to install on XenServer. Here is a tutorial: http://www.schirmacher.de/display/INFO/Install+smartmontools+on+Citrix+XenServer .

Comment: I'm assuming that this is only an answer to the "hdd" part of the question. Is there a solution for checking CPU temperature?